# pandas: slice on MultiIndex by range of first index, and choose secondary index label

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have some sales data grouped by `('dt', 'product_id')` like this:

```py
In [43]: sub.head()
Out[43]:
                           income
dt          product_id
2015-01-15  10016          23
2015-01-15  10017          188
2015-01-15  10018          NaN
2015-01-16  10016          188
2015-01-17  10025         1000
# this goes on and on...
```

how can I view the income of product `10016` in between `2015-01-15` and `2015-01-16`, and it's best that I can just slice this huge dataframe using the given MultiIndex, cause the data is relatively large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.xs()` is a good way to do slicing in multi-level index. 
And `.loc` to further extract the required date intervals you want.

```
import pandas as pd

# your df
# =======================
print(df)

Out[82]: 
                       income
dt         product_id        
2015-01-15 10016           23
           10017          188
           10018          NaN
2015-01-16 10016          188
2015-01-17 10025         1000

# one possible way
# ==========================================
df.xs(10016, level='product_id').loc['2015-01-15':'2015-01-16']

Out[88]: 
            income
dt                
2015-01-15      23
2015-01-16     188
```

Comment: can I select multiple product_ids as well?